# Action Cable not working after binding with ip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I have implemented action cable of rails-5 in my system and it's work fine on `localhost`, but when i tried to bind with ip it's give below error message.

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.1.46:3002/cable' failed: Error
>   during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

and in terminal log

> Failed to upgrade to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION:
>   Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)

I have made changes on my `development.rb` as like

```
config.action_cable.url = "ws://192.168.1.46:3002/cable"
```

but not succeed.

please guide me where i am wrong.

tell me if you need extra information, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add below line to `config/environments/development.rb` file

```
config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [/http:\/\/*/, /https:\/\/*/]
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Even better, only whitelist the domains that you really want to allow. For example: `config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [/http:\/\/www\.mydomain\.com/, /https:\/\/www\.mydomain\.com/]`