# rails 5, NGINX Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Tags: nginx, websocket, ruby-on-rails-5, puma

I try to deploy an simple web chat to server (nginx/puma). But I receive error console of browser:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://domain.com/cable' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

My config server domain.conf:

```
upstream backend {
  server unix:///var/run/backend.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80 ;
  server_name domain.com;

  root /home/rails/backend/public;
  access_log /home/rails/backend/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/rails/backend/log/nginx.error.log info;

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @backend;
  location @backend {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://backend;
  }

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  location /cable {
        proxy_pass http://gifty;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      }
}
```

Is it wrong some where? AnyOne setup it before. Please help me work out it

Comment: Did you fix it?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I too am stuck with this...

Comment: My issue turned out to be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38719359/action-cable-not-working-after-binding-with-ip). Hope this will help someone.